# Why can't I import my turtle module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I use Python, and for a school project, I needed to import Turtle for a drawing program. At the start of my program, I added:
`from turtle import *`
When I ran the finished program, an syntax error popped up in the terminal/shell.
[picture of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf6bV.png)
I tried reiterating my code, from using the "import turtle" to aliasing, but nothing worked. What could possibly be happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please show the code so that we can check it

Comment: here's the link to a notion page with my code, please don't look at any other pages there: https://www.notion.so/program-bcbf3b9470eb4322991bedc4b3deb798

Comment: This happened to me on VS Code too, it happens when you run the program using the green play button .Try using f5 to start your program and it should work, if not please tell me what platform you are using to run the code and I could help!

Comment: @JonathanDrukker thanks! I use vs code too so I used f5 like you said and it worked! Big tops to you for helping me.

Comment: Can you mark my answer ?It's down below.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a module in python, you can import using `import turtle` and you need to specify the module before each function like

```
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
```

If you import turtle using `from turtle import *`, you only need to call the functions from the module, like:

```
forward(100)
left(90)
forward(100)
```

You can also do: `import turtle as t` and do:

```
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
```

Comment: I knew that, but what I was asking for was how to fix it. I changed the syntax when I changed how I imported the modules, but they still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on VS Code too, it happens when you run the program using the green play button .Try using f5 to start your program and it should work. Hope this works!